# Use 1 executable file to be distributed accross 100 client PROS and CONS guys?

Tags: security, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, server-setup, manage

for easy updates of our internal system I'm planning to use just 1 exe located at the server and just put a shortcut in my clients pointed at the exe in the server. PROS and CONS guys? Server 2008 R2 and W7 as client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my thoughts based on my understanding:

pros --

1) easier to manage ? easier to upgrade - apply bug fixes , security patches etc.

2)save some disk space

3)saves the headache of maintaining same version for all clients:

cons:

1)has network dependency
2)what if the server hosting the exe goes down ? we need to worry about redundancy
3)performance issue on the centralized host can crop up

hope this helps